How to switch from fontenc to fontspec to use special characters without changing the document's overall formatting?
I'm trying to write an article using this Overleaf template: Instructions for COLING 2025 Proceedings
The template suggests using pdfLaTeX by default, but suggests that XeLaTeX is also acceptable as it is "especially suitable for text in non-Latin scripts". I need to use certain special characters, such as the tironian et, which are not possible in pdfLaTeX, so I have to use XeLaTeX instead. I removed \pdfoutput=1 and \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} from the .tex file, and switched the engine in the Overleaf menu.
The template uses \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, and to get the character I want to use I need to use \usepackage{fontspec} then \newfontfamily\ser{Noto Serif}. Unfortunately as soon as I include the fontspec package, the formatting of the whole document changes. Not only is this not the necessary formatting style, but it's also a lot larger text, which means it pushes the article I've written over the 8 page limit. I need to use the original formatting for most of the document, and only switch to individual fontspec characters as I need to use them. Is this possible?
Alternatively, is it possible to setup the template to use fontspec instead of fontenc, but for the output to match the formatting of the original template which used fontenc?

fontspec has a key Scale use it to reduce the noto font to match the original.

don't do that. you need to comment out the times package and use a similar font. you might try e.g. \setmainfont{TeXGyreTermes}. then comment inconsolata (probably) and set up the typewriter font for Inconsolata. and do something similar for whatever they're using for sans. I'm assuming you're getting latin modern rather than noto - unless you did something more than you said in your question. not a huge font, but bigger than times.

clarification: 'don't do that' was a response to @yannisl's suggestion and not anything the OP said. there's no reason to think the document as a whole is in noto and, if it is, scaling it is not the solution. scaling noto to match times will look awful and isn't anyway possible as the proportions will be wrong.

@cfr  the OP missed to show a MWE the paper should be written as article and load the package lrec-coling2024. It detects luatex or xelatex loads fontspec and texgyre  otf fonts etc. Scaling would only apply to the \ser command, rest of document would be left untouched.

@cfr Pathetically the conference organizers, updated guidelines for word but not for LaTeX, I had to look at the package, I quoted above which I downloaded it from their website. It is IMHO inconceivable for a computational linguistics conference NOT to recommend anything else than LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX.

@yannisl the source the OP linked to loads times and inconsolata, so if that's what the OP is using then ... but now I'm not clear what the OP is or isn't using or whether we are even looking at the same thing!

@yannisl I hope you're a devotee of Descartes in that case ... :-).

@cfr  We re looking at the same thing but is a Schrödinger's cat:)

@cfr you say you're not clear what I'm using or not. I'm able to recreate the problem in the blank template just by following the steps I mentioned in my post. I can post screenshots of the difference if that would help. But, as far as I can tell, apart from the changes I listed in the original post, I haven't changed anything. Am I to take it that commenting out times and using a different package is the solution? Thanks to both of you for the input, by the way.

The coling package makes no decision about font encoding and main font for the document.
You can use a clone of Times instead of \usepackage{times} (which, by the way, has been deprecated for a few decades).
Here's a sample, up to where the Tironian et is used by way of example.
% This must be in the first 5 lines to tell arXiv to use pdfLaTeX, which is strongly recommended.
%\pdfoutput=1
% In particular, the hyperref package requires pdfLaTeX in order to break URLs across lines.

\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% Change "review" to "final" to generate the final (sometimes called camera-ready) version.
% Change to "preprint" to generate a non-anonymous version with page numbers.
\usepackage[review]{coling}

% Standard package includes
%\usepackage{times}
%\usepackage{latexsym}

\usepackage{fontspec}

% For proper rendering and hyphenation of words containing Latin characters (including in bib files)
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% For Vietnamese characters
% \usepackage[T5]{fontenc}
% See https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf for other character sets

% This assumes your files are encoded as UTF8
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% This is not strictly necessary, and may be commented out,
% but it will improve the layout of the manuscript,
% and will typically save some space.
\usepackage{microtype}

% This is also not strictly necessary, and may be commented out.
% However, it will improve the aesthetics of text in
% the typewriter font.
%\usepackage{inconsolata}

%Including images in your LaTeX document requires adding
%additional package(s)
\usepackage{graphicx}

% If the title and author information does not fit in the area allocated, uncomment the following
%
%\setlength\titlebox{<dim>}
%
% and set <dim> to something 5cm or larger.

%%%% FONT SETUP

\setmainfont{texgyretermes}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
]
\setmonofont{Inconsolatazi4}[
  Scale=MatchLowercase,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-Regular,
  BoldFont=*-Bold,
]
\newfontfamily\ser{Noto Serif}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\title{Instructions for COLING 2025 Proceedings}

% Author information can be set in various styles:
% For several authors from the same institution:
% \author{Author 1 \and ... \and Author n \\
%         Address line \\ ... \\ Address line}
% if the names do not fit well on one line use
%         Author 1 \\ {\bf Author 2} \\ ... \\ {\bf Author n} \\
% For authors from different institutions:
% \author{Author 1 \\ Address line \\  ... \\ Address line
%         \And  ... \And
%         Author n \\ Address line \\ ... \\ Address line}
% To start a separate ``row'' of authors use \AND, as in
% \author{Author 1 \\ Address line \\  ... \\ Address line
%         \AND
%         Author 2 \\ Address line \\ ... \\ Address line \And
%         Author 3 \\ Address line \\ ... \\ Address line}

\author{First Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\\And
  Second Author \\
  Affiliation / Address line 1 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 2 \\
  Affiliation / Address line 3 \\
  \texttt{email@domain} \\}

%\author{
%  \textbf{First Author\textsuperscript{1}},
%  \textbf{Second Author\textsuperscript{1,2}},
%  \textbf{Third T. Author\textsuperscript{1}},
%  \textbf{Fourth Author\textsuperscript{1}},
%\\
%  \textbf{Fifth Author\textsuperscript{1,2}},
%  \textbf{Sixth Author\textsuperscript{1}},
%  \textbf{Seventh Author\textsuperscript{1}},
%  \textbf{Eighth Author \textsuperscript{1,2,3,4}},
%\\
%  \textbf{Ninth Author\textsuperscript{1}},
%  \textbf{Tenth Author\textsuperscript{1}},
%  \textbf{Eleventh E. Author\textsuperscript{1,2,3,4,5}},
%  \textbf{Twelfth Author\textsuperscript{1}},
%\\
%  \textbf{Thirteenth Author\textsuperscript{3}},
%  \textbf{Fourteenth F. Author\textsuperscript{2,4}},
%  \textbf{Fifteenth Author\textsuperscript{1}},
%  \textbf{Sixteenth Author\textsuperscript{1}},
%\\
%  \textbf{Seventeenth S. Author\textsuperscript{4,5}},
%  \textbf{Eighteenth Author\textsuperscript{3,4}},
%  \textbf{Nineteenth N. Author\textsuperscript{2,5}},
%  \textbf{Twentieth Author\textsuperscript{1}}
%\\
%\\
%  \textsuperscript{1}Affiliation 1,
%  \textsuperscript{2}Affiliation 2,
%  \textsuperscript{3}Affiliation 3,
%  \textsuperscript{4}Affiliation 4,
%  \textsuperscript{5}Affiliation 5
%\\
%  \small{
%    \textbf{Correspondence:} \href{mailto:email@domain}{email@domain}
%  }
%}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
This document is a supplement to the general instructions for COLING 2025 authors. It contains instructions for using the \LaTeX{} style files for COLING 2025.
The document itself conforms to its own specifications, and is therefore an example of what your manuscript should look like.
These instructions should be used both for papers submitted for review and for final versions of accepted papers.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

Tironian {\ser ⁊}

These instructions are for authors submitting papers to the COLING 2025 conference using \LaTeX. They are not self-contained. All authors must follow the general instructions for COLING 2025 proceedings which are an adaptation of (or rely on) the general instructions for ACL proceedings\footnote{\url{http://acl-org.github.io/ACLPUB/formatting.html}}, and this document contains additional instructions for the \LaTeX{} style files.

[...]

\end{document}



If you download the author's kit from the websit you get: \usepackage[review]{lrec-coling2024} % this is the new style. Which does make decisions when you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.  They failed to update their write-up:)
